# initializing Foreign Key models in code has no effect

Tags: python, django

I have a foreign key model like this:

```
invite_discount_owner = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name='aaa', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           related_name='invited_customer')
```

and in some part of my code, I want to initialize it with a correct data type:

```
request.user.invite_discount_owner = discount_owner
```

but it has no effect and this field stays empty!

Comment: also after you save `request.user`?

Comment: I didn't save anything @dirkgroten

Comment: order.invite_discount_amount = 50000
                    order.calc_price()
                    if not request.user.invite_discount_owner:

                        discount_owner = User.objects.filter(mobile=discount_code)[0]
                        order.return_customer_credit(user=discount_owner, force_price=50000)
                        request.user.invite_discount_owner = discount_owner
                        request.user.invite_discount_owner.save()

Comment: the problem was saving, Thanks @dirkgroten